# Slack. How to download image in url_private property using PHP?

Tags: php, slack-api, slack

I am trying to download a png image from Slack and save it into a file but the only thing that gets saved into the file is HTML code for the login page of Slack.

This is what I have tried.

```
$url = 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/XXXXXX-XXXXXXX/download/2016-07-11.png';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen('/assets/tmp/1.png', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
            ));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

If I access the link in browser while logged into Slack, the image downloads just fine, but not through the PHP code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you are sure that Authorization header is the only one header you need to download the image?

Comment: It's here in the docs. [Docs](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/working-with-files). The docs is in Python. The only header added is Authorization header.

Comment: Please post an error message

Comment: There's no error. I was expecting the image from the url to be saved in the path '/assets/tmp/1.png'. But only the html code for the login page is saved into the file. There is this message 'You need to sign in to see this page.' in the login page.

Comment: You should check your api token and permission. Is it ok?

Comment: @DmitriyTroyan That was exactly the problem. I had sent a support ticket to Slack team as well. After I read the reply from slack I realized that I probably needed an extra permission scope to read files and of course I had not added files:read to my application. The code downloads the files just fine now. Thank you for taking the time to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

I needed an extra permission scope to read files. I added files:read permission scope to my application from Slack Developer Console and the code works as expected.